# Mat-card image placement next to mat-card-content

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to place, an image side by side with text that will describe it like so:
[image]

However, I am trying to do this in an angular mat-card and I have tried to initially do it with `mat-card-content` but that failed so I resorted to calling `mat-card` and then using divs inside however that doesn't render correctly:

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<mat-card class="projects">
    <div>
        <div class="box">
            <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/jupiterTop.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
                Text to be placed next to the picture
        </div>

    </div>
</mat-card>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

I cannot find any examples where this is done so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
NOTE: Resizing of the image is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have flex layout in your project [link](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). You can do something like the below:

```
<mat-card fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <span>Text to be placed next to picture</span>
    <img src="../../assets/jupiterTop.jpg" />
</mat-card>
```

If you don't have flex layout and don't want to use it for some reason I'd suggest looking up flexbox and learning how to use that.

Comment: Hey Kyle, I tried to use your suggestion but it is entirely incorrect and renders the image extremely large to the right of the card while the text goes to the top of the card.

Comment: Do you have the flex-layout package installed?  I tested it in my project and it rendered correctly.  I didn't size your image so it's going to be whatever size it is.  The real point of my answer is to look in to flex though.  Generally speaking, float is not the recommended approach for layout in 2019.

Comment: Here is a stack blitz without flex-layout just using straight flex: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ime5qq-mbeu1e)

Comment: Understood, I am a beginner with CSS and it seems a lot of the functions "appear" to do the same thing but they all have differences and grasping them is a little difficult. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

Using `mat-card-content` is the proper approach since you want to do a custom layout inside the content. You just need to put the image together with the text in the content for the float to work as you expect. Also do not use the `mat-card-image` directive since it adds other styling you don't need.

Here is your code changed to a working version:

```
<mat-card class="projects">
    <mat-card-content>
        <div>
            <img class="box" src="../../assets/jupiterTop.jpg">
            Text to be placed next to the picture
        <div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Your CSS is good.

I have created also a [working sample on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ime5qq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-fancy-example.html) where you can see it in action.

Comment: So thank you for this solution, it goes a long way in getting me on the right path, however there are two points of concern, upon resizing the window for example really small, the image leaves the mat-card entirely, or if you make the window too large, the image becomes too large. Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: I would also like to keep the text and the image partitioned so that the text never flows into the side of the image

Comment: As you already figured out for this case the other answer is better flex-layout is better to do it the way you want.